# detecting dlib rectangle coordinates in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

- i'm working on college computer vision project but stuck at getting coordinates of the bounding box generated by train_object_detector.

  1. i searched through entire documentation but was unable to find the function for getting coordinates in c++. i know about python but i need in c++. studied the abstracts of rectangle.h but of no avail.
  2. been trying on this since yesterday but still no success. what i'm missing?

     rectangle (
         const rectangle& rect
     );
     long left (
     )

Comment: What's the problem? Converting `dlib::rectangle` to `cv::Rect`? Or what?

Comment: ok. i got it maybe. you mean i need to first convert dlib rectangle to opencv. right? do you have any link for a example program to do so?

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what you want to do.. which is very unclear right now.

Comment: it should be as simple as `cv::Rect dlib2cv(const dlib::rectangle& r) {return cv::Rect(r.left(), r.top(), r.width(), r.height());}`

Comment: i just want to get corner coordinates of the rectangle i.e image so that i can modify that area of image accordingly

Comment: sorry, i mistakenly marked it as answer in hurry. i'm having difficulty including both opencv and dlib files. functions are merging kind of.

Comment: please improve your question so we can understand what you are asking about. please post your code and describe errors you god. And dlib has a lot of examples - try to start with modifying them

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative way to get the coordinates of dlib::rectangle object. 
Assumption: u're using c++ to do this and the object identifier is A. dlib::rectangle has the ff. methods to access its coordinates.

`A.left(), A. top(), A.right() and A.bottom() for x, y, w, and h`  respectively.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a better identifier than `A`. The uppercase variable name is a little bit unconventional too.